# Android Studio reporting Date error

Tags: android, android-studio

I have the following class:

```
public class ModelCalendarDay {
    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;

   // ......
}
```

I have this method:

```
public Date getDate() {
    GregorianCalendar thatDay = (GregorianCalendar) GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    thatDay.set(year, (month - 1), day, 0, 0, 0);
    return thatDay.getTime();
}
```

Although I can still launch the app, Android Studio complains about the `(month - 1)` bit: `Must be one of Calendar.January, Calendar.February, etc`

How can this be fixed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=76090 and will be fixed in Android Studio 0.8.13.

The comment marking it as fixed says this:

> Fixed for 0.8.13. (Note: It may require File > Invalidate Caches... / Restart to update the cached annotations metdata).